# DB2 query performance

Tags: sql, db2-luw

The purpose of the below query is to join the same table which have two different kind of sources and find out where the N_ID matches or L_ID matches.
Below query is executing in SQL server in 2 minutes, whereas when I execute the same query in DB2 , its taking 1 hour. It would be good if someone can help to improve the performance. Whether index columns will solve the issue or is there any other way I need to rewrite the query. We have around 17 million records with source as E and around 2 million records with source <>'E'. I am using DB2 10.5. Currently there is no index in place for this tables

```
    select ID from TABLE where N_ID  in(select N_ID from TABLE where N_ID in(
select aa.N_ID from
(select N_ID from TABLE where SOURCE<>'E')aa
INNER JOIN
(select N_ID from TABLE where SOURCE='E' )bb
on aa.N_ID=bb.N_ID))
 UNION 
 select ID from TABLE where L_ID in(
(select aa.L_ID from
(select L_ID from TABLE where SOURCE<>'E')aa
INNER JOIN
(select L_ID from TABLE where SOURCE='E' )bb
on aa.L_ID=bb.L_ID ))
```

Now I rewrite the above query in such a way that its getting finished in 7 minutes

```
select ID from TABLE where N_ID in(
select aa.N_ID from
(select SRC.N_ID from TABLE SRC,TABLE REF 
where SRC.SOURCE<>'E' and REF.SOURCE='E' and
SRC.N_ID=REF.N_ID)aa)

 UNION ALL

select INT_CIL_ID from TABLE where LEI_CODE in(
select aa.LEI_CODE from
(select SRC.LEI_CODE from TABLE SRC,TABLE REF 
where SRC.SOURCE<>'E' and REF.SOURCE='E' and
SRC.LEI_CODE=REF.LEI_CODE)aa)
```

In the similar note I have same issue with the below query as well where in sql server its working in 3 minutes and DB2 is running forever.

```
select aa.ID from 
(select case 
when L_NAME is not null then L_NAME
When L_NAME is null then O_NAME
else L_NAME
END O_NAME,ID,FIRSTNAME,SecondName from TABLE where SOURCE<>'EXTERNAL')aa
INNER JOIN
(select case 
when L_NAME is not null then L_NAME
When L_NAME is null then O_NAME
else L_NAME
END O_NAME,ID,FIRSTNAME,SecondName from TABLE where SOURCE='EXTERNAL' )bb
on  
aa.O_NAME=bb.O_NAME
UNION
select bb.ID from 
(select  case 
when L_NAME is not null then L_NAME
When L_NAME is null then O_NAME
else L_NAME
END O_NAME,ID,FIRSTNAME,SecondName from .TABLE where SOURCE<>'EXTERNAL')aa
INNER JOIN
(select case 
when L_NAME is not null then L_NAME
When L_NAME is null then O_NAME
else L_NAME
END O_NAME,ID,FIRSTNAME,SecondName from .TABLE where SOURCE='EXTERNAL' )bb
on  
aa.O_NAME=bb.O_NAME
UNION
select ID from TABLE where replace(FIRSTNAME,' ','') in(
select distinct aa.FIRSTNAME from
(select distinct replace(FIRSTNAME,' ','')FIRSTNAME from TABLE where SOURCE<>'EXTERNAL' and FIRSTNAME is not null)aa
INNER JOIN
(select distinct replace(FIRSTNAME,' ','')FIRSTNAME from TABLE where SOURCE='EXTERNAL' and FIRSTNAME is not null)bb
on aa.FIRSTNAME=bb.FIRSTNAME)
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to really help without looking at the physical characteristics of your tables, and if you are comparing apples-to-apples with SQL Server. E.g. do the tables have the same indexes etc on both systems. Also an explain plan of the SQL would help

You SQL does not look too in-efficient on the fact of it, but you could try something like this in place of the *first* part of your last query. It explicitly joins for the 4 possible cases

```
WITH
    T1 AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE where SOURCE = 'EXTERNAL')
,   T2 AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE where SOURCE <> 'EXTERNAL')
select T1.ID FROM T1 JOIN T2 USING ( L_NAME )
UNION
select T1.ID FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.L_NAME = T2.O_NAME WHERE T2.L_NAME IS NULL
UNION
select T1.ID FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.O_NAME = T2.T_NAME WHERE T1.L_NAME IS NULL
UNION
select T1.ID FROM T1 JOIN T2 USING ( O_NMAE )WHERE T1.L_NAME IS NULL AND T2.L_NAME IS NULL
```

If this helps that part of the query, then try other similar rewrites elsewhere